# Team City Build step fail with "Could not find file 'C:\Users\tfsbuild\.nuget\packages\system.xml.xmldocument\4.3.0\system.xml.xmldocument.nuspec'"

Tags: teamcity, asp.net-core-2.0

Trying to "restore" a .Net Core 2 project in Team City and get

> Could not find file 'C:\Users\tfsbuild.nuget\packages\system.xml.xmldocument\4.3.0\system.xml.xmldocument.nuspec'.

in the build log. I know it might be a bit early to try building with Team City but thinking that someone migh have figured it out? Since both the Nuget Installer step and the dotNet Core restore give the same error maybe it is something I've overlooked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it is related to user permissions. Changing the build agent back from a custom domain user to SYSTEM it solved the problem.